# Удаление не выделенных строк таблицы и сохранение

Tags: javascript

нужно чтобы при нажатии кнопки, например расположенной внизу таблицы, удалялись все не выделенные чекбоксом строки. Ниже код таблицы. Так же нужно, чтобы все изменения таблицы было сохранено. Объясню как это все должно будет работать: данную форму будут открывать несколько человек, каждый из них по очереди откроет форму и в таблице нажмет соответствующий чекбокс после он должен будет сохранить форму, чтобы другие при открытии видели выделенные чекбоксы. После всех выделений последний нажмет на кнопку "Удалить Лишние" и таблица сформируется только по выделенным строкам (чекбоксам) и также сохранит файл (локально), уже как итоговый.

```js
document.write("<h1>Форма</h1>");

FIO = [
  "",
  "Е.В. Иванов, начальник отдела",
  "А.А. Соколов, инженер 1 категории",
  "Ю.В. Сидоров, инженер 1 категории",
  "Ю.Е. Трудный, инженер 1 категории",
  "А.В. Башман, инженер 1 категории",
  "В.В. Вилов, инженер 1 категории",
  "Е.А. Петров, инженер 1 категории"
];

document.write('<table border = "1">')
for (var i = 1; i < FIO.length; i++) { // если var i=0; то появится "АВУ1", тоесть при i=1 список формируется со 2 строки

  document.write("<tr>");
  document.write("<td>");
  document.write(i);
  document.write("</td>");
  document.write("<td>");
  document.write(FIO[i]);
  document.write("</td>");
  document.write("<td>");
  document.write("<input type='checkbox'>");
  document.write("</td>");
  document.write("</tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");
```

Comment: Через `document.write()` такое делать, это конечно жестоко..

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону document.createElement и методов append, appendChild.

Comment: + то что вы дополнили и ваш код - это вообще не то. Для многопользовательской работы вам вообще нужен сервер

Comment: Документ будет храниться в сетевой папке и его по очереди будут открывать, ставить галочки и закрывать, вот нужно что бы эти галочки сохранялись, я дамал localStorage хватит. или нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

функция удаления невыделенных строк:

```
document.write("<h1>Форма</h1>");

FIO = [
  "",
  "Е.В. Иванов, начальник отдела",
  "А.А. Соколов, инженер 1 категории",
  "Ю.В. Сидоров, инженер 1 категории",
  "Ю.Е. Трудный, инженер 1 категории",
  "А.В. Башман, инженер 1 категории",
  "В.В. Вилов, инженер 1 категории",
  "Е.А. Петров, инженер 1 категории"
];

document.write('<table border = "1">')
for (var i = 1; i < FIO.length; i++) { // если var i=0; то появится "АВУ1", тоесть при i=1 список формируется со 2 строки
  document.write("<tr>");
  document.write("<td>");
  document.write(i);
  document.write("</td>");
  document.write("<td>");
  document.write(FIO[i]);
  document.write("</td>");
  document.write("<td>");
  document.write("<input type='checkbox'>");
  document.write("</td>");
  document.write("</tr>");
}
document.write("</table>");
document.write("<button>Remove unchecked</button>")

function removeRows() {
    const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')
    
    Array.from(inputs)
        .filter(input => !input.checked)
        .forEach(input => {
            const row = input.closest('tr')
            
            row.remove()
        })

    Array.from(inputs)
        .filter(input => input.checked)
        .forEach((input, idx) => {
            const row = input.closest('tr')
            const first = row.children[0]

            first.textContent = idx + 1
        })
}

const btn = document.querySelector('button')

btn.onclick = removeRows
```

Comment: Я только начинаю изучать Javascript, подскажите как данную функцию вставить в общий код чтобы все работало?

Comment: выбираете button на странице любым удобным способом. далее навешивате слушатель события клика: `button.addEventListener('click', removeRows)`

Comment: Добрый день, попробовал сделать и чет не работает: <button type="submit" id="submit">Удалить лишнее!</button>
    
    <script>   
       
        <input type="submit" id="submit">
    button.addEventListener('click', removeRows)
        function removeRows() {
   const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')
   
   inputs
       .filter(input => !input.checked)
       .forEach(input => {
           const row = input.closest('tr')
           
           row.remove()
       })
}
            
     </script>

Comment: @DEW, что конкретно не работает? и зачем на кнопке `type="submit"`?

Comment: не получается вставить ваш код в мой, если не сложно покажите как это делается, пример можно на почту сбросить dew1582@ya.ru, спасибо.

Comment: @DEW, переписал ответ и протестировал. все работает

Comment: Да, посмотрел работает, есть один ньюанс, когда удаляются не выделенные строки то нумерация остается та же, например выделив 3 и 5 строку при удалении номера строки остаются 3 и 5 а как сделать чтобы снова нумерация шла 1, 2, 3, и так далее?

Comment: @DEW, обновил (это уже могли и сами попробовать сделать). если ответ полезен, пометьте как правильный

Comment: Да все правильно, спасибо огромное.